# XMPHP doesn't work in local

Tags: php, xmpp, xmpphp

I have a problem with XMPPHP downloaded from this address :

http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/downloads/list

I downloaded the last one in the list (Jul 2009)

Actually, I run Jabber in local (development mode) .. and I want to test sending chat messages , so I wrote the following :

```
$xmpp = new XMPPHP_XMPP('host.lan', 5280,'serverUser','serverPass','resource', 'xmpphp');
$xmpp->connect(30, true, true);
$xmpp->message('user@host.lan', 'Hello there , this is a test from the mobile version');
$xmpp->disconnect();
```

there are no error messages, no warnings , everything says the message has been sent. But I wonder if it's not working in local.

And forgot to say, I'm using PHP 5.4 , if the XMPP Version I downloaded doesn't work for php 5.4 , download links will be appreciated .

thank you in advance

Comment: You have to specify a bit more. What is the problem? Any error messages? Logs? I tried that once and it worked.

Comment: there's no error messages, no warnings , everything says the message was sent. But I wonder if it's not working in local

Comment: Actually it must work in local.. because I have already another chat version with Javascript... which is working good in the standard version (cause now I'm avoiding js for mobile use)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable debug:

`$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP(
    'host', port, 
    'username', 
    'pws', 
    'resource', 
    'domain', 
    $printlog=True, 
    $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);`